# VB code searching all excel file in given folder or directory

Tags: vba, excel, qtp

Please see below code its working fine and searching for all excel files in given directory. But I am not able to understand this code

Doubt : `NoOfFolders(Iterator1`) is a dynamic array and when again function is called `fnFolderStructure` , `NoOfFolders` array is again created. But even values `NoOfFolders(0)` and `NoOfFolders(1`) changed but still when again its is called with previous values.

How it is able to retain values even after writing of `NoOfFolders(Iterator1)`.

```
fnCheckFiles("C:\Temp\Sahil")

Function fnFolderStructure(sAddress)
        i=0
        Dim NoOfFolders()
        Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        Set objFolder2 = objFSO1.GetFolder(sAddress) 
        Set FolderIn=objFolder2.SubFolders
        Set FileIn=objFolder2.Files

'       If FileIn.Count>0 Then
'            fnCheckFiles(sAddress)
'       End If  

    If FolderIn.Count>0 Then    
        y=FolderIn.Count        
        ReDim NoOfFolders(y-1)  

        For Each objSubfolder in FolderIn
             NoOfFolders(i)= objSubfolder.Name 
             i=i+1
        Next

        For Iterator1 = 0 To y-1
            sPath1=sAddress&"\"&NoOfFolders(Iterator1)
            fnCheckFiles(sPath1)
        Next

'            Set colSubfolders = FolderIn.Subfolders
'           Call fnFolderStructure(sPath1)
        End If
End Function

Function fnCheckFiles(sAddress)
            Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
            Set objFolder4 = objFSO1.GetFolder(sAddress)        
            ''sFileName=objFolder4.Name
            For Each objFile In objFolder4.Files 
                sFileName=objFile.Name              
                if (InStr(1,sFileName,"xlsx",1)) then       
                    msgbox objFile.Name     
                End IF      
            Next


        if objFolder4.SubFolders.Count>0 then
            fnFolderStructure(sAddress)
        End if
End Function
```

Comment: i'm not sure if i fully understand your question, but if you redim an array and you want to keep the existing values, you need to use redim preserve.

besides that, do you need to store the names in an array - if you're not doing anything else than using them in the for-loop it might be easier to integrate your for-iterator-loop in the first loop.

Comment: Hi , The path which I have given is "C:\Temp\Sahil" Suppose there are two folders A,B. A folder has one excel sheet "A.xlsx" and folder C. Folder C has one more excel "C.xlsx". Now Folder B which is in folder "C:\Temp\Sahil" is having one folder "F" and excel "B.xlsx". And folder "F" has excel "F.xlsx". So this code will name all excel in each folder by calling functions in recursion.And NoOfFolders array is redefined and value new assigned again and again. So how come its still retaining Value. And how this code works. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How it is able to retain values even after writing of
>   NoOfFolders(Iterator1)

The array is not being written to by that statement.  The array NoOfFolders is used in four places...

1) Declares the value as a dynamic array

```
Dim NoOfFolders()
```

2) Redimensions the variable to match the size of the number of folder names it will hold

```
ReDim NoOfFolders(y - 1)
```

3) Assigns the name of a folders to the corresponding position in the array.  This is the only place where values are written to the array.

```
NoOfFolders(i) = objSubFolder.Name
```

4) Reads the name of a folder from the array to build a path of a sub-folder

```
sPath1 = sAddress & "\" & NoOfFolders(Iterator1)
```

Comment: Hi , The path which I have given is "C:\Temp\Sahil" Suppose there are two folders A,B. A folder has one excel sheet "A.xlsx" and folder C. Folder C has one more excel "C.xlsx". Now Folder B which is in folder "C:\Temp\Sahil" is having one folder "F" and excel "B.xlsx". And folder "F" has excel "F.xlsx". So this code will name all excel in each folder by calling functions in recursion.And NoOfFolders array is redefined and value new assigned again and again. So how come its still retaining Value. And how this code works.

Comment: The fnCheckFolders function is being called recursively since it keeps getting called for each sub-folder until no more sub-folders are found.  The array you are concerned about doesn't get redefined each time you call the function.  Instead, new memory is allocated for the function each time it is called, and the memory stays populated until you exit the function.  If your folder structure is three levels deep, you'll end up with 3 arrays present in memory at the same time, each holding the names of the sub-folders at that level of the folder structure.

Comment: Hi , I understand what you say that " new memory is allocated for the function each time it is called" . So it means NoOfFolders() array in above code will have different values at different level. Like NoOfFolders(0) is A at first level and it changes to NoOfFolders(0) "C" in third level. And when I come back it after execution NoOfFolders(0) will have again A instead of writting NoOfFolders(o) ="C". Can you please know any site where this concept is explained in detial. But really thanks for explaining this. Hats of to you :)

Comment: Happy to help.  This is one of those concepts I learned at some point over the past 15 years of programming, so I'm sorry to say I don't know of a good reference to point you to.  I did a quick Google search and didn't see anything that stood out.  Also, please remember to mark the answer I posted as accepted if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ====================================================================================================================*/
def getTagValue(def filepath, def tagName,log)
{
    def tagValue = ""
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder()
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath)
        // Get the root element
        Node company = doc.getFirstChild()
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
        //log.info "Nodes length :" +nodes.getLength()
        Node node = nodes.item(0)
        //log.info node.getTextContent()
        tagValue = node.getTextContent()
        if(tagValue == "")
        {
            tagValue = "tag not found"
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.error e.message
        tagValue = "tag not found"
    }
    return tagValue
}
```

==============================
def List readXpaths(def expectedExcelPath, def expectedExcelSheet, log, context)
        {

```
        Fillo.Connection con=getFilloConnection(expectedExcelPath,log)
        String sQuery="Select * from "+expectedExcelSheet+" where TestCaseName='"+context.testCase.name+"'"
        //log.info sQuery

        Recordset rs=getRecordSet(con,sQuery,log)
        List<String> colList=rs.getFieldNames()
        colList.remove("TestCaseName")
        colList.remove("DATA_SET")
        colList.remove("RUN")
        List<String> xpaths=new ArrayList<String>()
        while(rs.next())
        {
            for(String str:colList)
            {           
                if(rs.getField(str)!="")
                {
                    xpaths.add(rs.getField(str))

                }
            }
        }
        return xpaths;
    }
```